# Obtener ID de URL amiglable en laravel

Tags: laravel-5, url

Tengo un controlador index que me muestra todos los registros (sin filtros) de la consulta:

id, titulo, descripcion, provincia, ciudad entre otro en la página principal

cada uno de ellos al mostrarse en la página principal genera un enlace para mostrar el detalle de cada uno de esos registro en una página nueva, pero la URL es amigable y no lleva el ID en dicha URL, muestro la composición de esa URL: www.midominio.com/titulo-provincia-ciudad

en mi página de detalle quisiera filtrar los resultados por el id, cómo hago para obtenerlo?

Comment: Como lo tienes en tu archivo de rutas?

Comment: @Dohko19 gracias, creo que ya se como resolverlo... Yo logré lo que deseaba (Filtrar el resultado con un dato adicional que pasé a la URL que es unico en cada registro (Un código), voy a intentar pasando el ID por la URL y capturándolo en la ruta. Gracias

Comment: Me alegro leer eso, mucha suerte